# How to replace sumBy with sumOf in kotlin 1.5

Tags: kotlin

I have the following code:

```
val sum = list.itens.sumBy { item ->
    when (item.intValueI == item.intValueII) {
        true -> 1
        else -> 0
    }
}
```

Updating to `Kotlin 1.5`, I got the `deprecated` warning; How should I proceed to achieve the same functionality?

I tried below:

```
val result = list.itens.sumOf<ListItemClass> { item ->
    val intValueI = item.value ?: 0
    val intValueII = item.valueII ?: 0
    when(item.intValueI == item.IntValueII){
        true -> 1
        else -> 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not filter your items and count them instead of involving maths, since that seems like what you're after?

```
val sum = list.items.filter { it.intValue1 == it.intValue2 }.size
```

Or, even more simply (thanks Tenfour04 in comments!):

```
val sum = list.items.count { it.intValue1 == it.intValue2 }
```

If it's absolutely essential for some reason to use `sumOf`, a slightly hacky solution would be:

```
val sum = list.items.sumOf { 
  if (it.intValue2 == it.intValue2) 1 else 0 as Int
}
```

Looks like the compiler / Android Studio gets a bit confused when returning 1 & 0, hence needing an `else` of either `it.intValue1 * 0` or `0 as Int`. The former is messier, but the latter leaves a AS warning.

Comment: It solves, but how to write the ```selector``` for ```ListItem``` to achieve the same functionality?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The number of `item`s where the two int values match, right? Not sure what you mean about a selector (or ListItem).

Comment: I'm trying to understand what should be the "selector" described in the documentation[1]. The automatic replacement from the android studio failed.

[1] https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum-of.html

Comment: You don't need to use sumOf or a selector. Filtering and getting the size will provide an identical result with less logic and less code.

Comment: Even simpler: `val sum = list.items.count { it.intValueI == it.intValueII }`

Comment: @Tenfour04 Inexplicably forgot that existed, thanks. Have edited into answer, definitely better.

Comment: You can also put in `as Int` to avoid the hacky thing, although this triggers a No Cast Needed warning. Not sure why the compiler can't tell that 1 and 0 are both Ints and not Longs in this situation.

Comment: Replacing by the value * 0, solve the expression and the compiler is happy. Why is necessary this kind of logic?

Comment: It's a workaround for something that appears to be a compiler bug.

Comment: Agreed, Tenfour04. I have had to suppress several incorrect warnings like this one since upgrading from Kotlin 1.3 to 1.6